# Contar filas de una tabla html

Tags: javascript, html

**Hola** estoy tratando de contar las filas de una tabla `html` y mostrarlas con un `label` pero no encuentro como hacerlo, encontre la forma de hacerlo con `javaScript` pero la funcion la llama por medio de un `onclick` así :

```html
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Ejercicio</title>
     </head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script>
      function contarFilas() {
       var $num = document.getElementById('tblUsuario').getElementsByTagName('tr').length - 1;
       alert($num);
      }
     </script>
     <body>
      <table border="1" id="tblUsuario">
       <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Hinata</td>
        <td>Hyuga</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Yuno</td>
        <td>Gasai</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Asuna</td>
        <td>Yuuki</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="contarFilas()"/>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Pero como digo no busco que me salga así la cantidad de filas, lo que busco es que me salga en un label arriba de la tabla. Como podria realizarlo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si sólo tienes una tabla puedes contar los elementos `tr`, como en este ejemplo. Si hay más tablas o sólo quieres contar determinadas filas, puedes añadir diferentes clases a los `tr` y contar la cantidad de cada elemento, como he añadido en el segundo `div`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nrows = 0; var nres = 0;
     $("table tr").each(function() {
         nrows++;
     })
     $("#nrows").html(nrows);
     $(".isres").each(function() {
         nres++;
     })
     $("#nres").html(nres);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nrows"></div>
<div id="nres"></div>
        <table border="1" id="tblUsuario">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="isres">
                <td>Hinata</td>
                <td>Hyuga</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="isres">
                <td>Yuno</td>
                <td>Gasai</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="isres">
                <td>Asuna</td>
                <td>Yuuki</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente

Comment: No ahy de que :)